# Document Lookup Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow, document-library, lookup-column

all,

In SharePoint Online I have a doc library (Reference Docs) and a list (Projects).

The goal is for users to choose a doc from a lookup drop-down in Projects, which, when clicked, will directly open the chosen document stored in Reference Docs.

So, in Reference Docs I created a workflow that sets the value of the Title field with the Name field.

In Projects I created a lookup column referencing the Title field in Reference Docs

All works fine, except the link opens the document properties, not the document.

This should be simple, but I just can figure out what is incorrect.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You will need to post a screen capture, or details, of the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the workflow it is hard to understand what is happening.

They way I would approach this is to create a HYPERLINK column and set the URL to the files path and then set the display name as the files name like you have now. 
Then hide your TITLE column, and move the Hyperlink column to Position 1.

**Note:** I would edit the Hyperlink column to be a HYPERLINK type Not PICTURE in the list settings. This will work for sure, I have set this up in my environment and it is working as expected with a new window and everything

That way when you click the item, the file will open up and not just the properties panel.

Let me know if this works for you!

Thanks,
Kyle